# Parallel download for a list of urls and renaming

Tags: linux, wget

I have a list of tab-separated urls, and target file names, `urls_to_download.txt`, for example:

```
first_file.jpg\thttps://www.google.co.il/images/srpr/logo11w.png
/subdir_1/second_file.jpg\thttps://www.google.co.il/images/srpr/logo12w.png
...
last_file.jpg\thttps://www.google.co.il/images/srpr/logo99w.png
```

which I want to download using several connections.

This I can do, for example, by:

`cat urls_to_download.txt | xargs -n 1 -P 10 wget -nc`

My question is, how do I get the files to have the new names I want for them, so the output dir would have:

```
first_file.jpg
/subdir1/second_file.jpg
...
last_file.jpg
```

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing that something like this should work for you:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                       
while read FILENAME URL; do
  wget -nc -O "$FILENAME" "$URL"
done <input.txt
```

where input.txt is a file which contains tab separated file/url pairs, one per line.

Answer (score 2):

1. Note that the file names in your file are using an absolute path. So you'd better rewrite those names to a relative path.
2. In shell, only using `&` to put a process background can make your work parallel.

For example, if you want to be parallel, you do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read FILENAME URL
do
    wget -nc -O "./$FILENAME" "$URL" &   # So `wget` runs in background
done < input.txt
```

**NOTE**: The above script is just a hint and will create too many parallel `wget` processes if you have a lot of lines in `input.txt`. There are some ways to control the number of parallel tasks, which however are more or less complicated to a shell script.

A very simple way to control the number of parallel tasks, which ensures that there are at most 20 wget processes.

```
#!/bin/bash
NUMBER=0
while read FILENAME URL
do
    wget -nc -O "./$FILENAME" "$URL" &   # So `wget` runs in background
    NUMBER=$((NUMBER + 1))
    if [ $NUMBER -gt 20 ]
    then
        wait   # wait all background process to finish
        NUMBER=0
    fi
done < input.txt
wait
```

However, this method is so simple that it is not the most efficient and accurate way to control the number of parallel tasks.

Answer (score 0):

try this command to download you files concurrently:

```
`cut -f 2 urls_to_download.txt | wget -i -;` 

`cut -f 2 urls_to_download.txt | sed 's/.*\///' | while read f; do mv $f $(cut -f 1 urls_to_download.txt); done`
```

I can't find a way to rename the file properly with the `wget` option and you need to modify to make sure the directory exists in the `mv` command.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `wget`'s `-x` option:

> -x
>    --force-directories
>        The opposite of -nd---create a hierarchy of directories, even if one would not have been created
>        otherwise.  E.g. wget -x  http://fly.srk.fer.hr/robots.txt will save the downloaded file to
>        fly.srk.fer.hr/robots.txt.

```
xargs -n 1 -P 10 wget -nc < urls_to_download.txt
```

If your file is tab-delimited:

```
xargs -n 1 -d $'\t' -P 10 wget -nc -x < urls_to_download.txt
```

Or perhaps you can convert tabs to newlines:

```
sed -e 's|\t|\n|g' urls_to_download.txt | xargs -n 1 -P 10 wget -nc -x
```