# Curl and rename images using string from text file

Tags: curl, xargs

I have a TXT file containing a list of URLs like:

```
website/media/945746/ui4Q9EJoUEmVLtUNhtRX.JPG John.JPG
website/media/226251/6epk0CUwnhofAjZMP2xp.JPG Kelly.JPG
website/media/658552/Q4qQgLF2bvVwxI37jgQG.JPG Sharon.JPG
website/media/856214/8xlBzvlG4TNfKgo86gM6.JPG Bill.JPG
```

I am using `xargs -n 1 curl -O < urls.txt` to download the images.

How do I download the file so `ui4Q9EJoUEmVLtUNhtRX.JPG` is renamed as `John.JPG` , `6epk0CUwnhofAjZMP2xp.JPG` is renamed as `Kelly.JPG` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just reverse the order of two fields:

```sh
while read -r url name ; do
    curl -o $name $url
done < urls.txt
```

If you want concurrent download, let every curl command run in background and `wait` for them to finish.

PS: `-O` means output file name for `wget` not `curl`. `curl` uses `-o` instead.

Comment: I am copying and pasting the code you provided directly into cygwin and receive error `rl: (6) Could not resolve host: url`

Comment: Sigh... was on mobile... You are right. There is a missing dollar sign there.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me using **glee8e** answer and solution from **wojciii** at [Parallel download for a list of urls and renaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24731156/parallel-download-for-a-list-of-urls-and-renaming)

`#!/bin/bash
while read -r URL FILENAME; do
    curl -o "$FILENAME" "$URL"
done < urls.txt`